# Dereference 4 bytes pointer to 1 byte array

Tags: arrays, c

I have a program that looks like this

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t arr[10] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09};
    
    uint32_t *p = (uint32_t *)&arr[4];
    
    printf("Value of p: %02Xh\n", *p);

    return 0;
}
```

The output being printed is `7060504h` which is

```c
*p = (arr[7] << 24) | (arr[6] << 16) | (arr[5] << 8) | arr[4]; // (1)
```

I have the following questions:

1. Why is `arr[7]` MSB but not `arr[4]`?
2. Why is the output calculated following (1) not (2)?

```c
*p = (arr[1] << 24) | (arr[2] << 16) | (arr[3] << 8) | arr[4]; // (2)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that a violation of strict aliasing?

Comment: Let's talk about sex...... byte sex........ see https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/byte-order ..... and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 0):

> Why is `arr[7]` MSB but not `arr[4]`?

The C standard says, in C 2018 6.2.6.1: “Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number,
**order**, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or implementation-defined.”

This means a C implementation may put the bytes of an object in any order it chooses and documents. The implementation you are using puts the low-value byte at the low address and the big-value byte at the big address. This is called *little endian*. (The opposite order is *big endian*.)

> Why is the output calculated following (1) not (2)?

This question is unclear. Why would you expect an expression using elements 4, 5, 6, and 7 of the array to produce a value from elements 1, 2, 3, and 4?

> `uint32_t *p = (uint32_t *)&arr[4];`

The behavior of using `*p` defined this way is not defined by the C standard. It results in an array of `uint8_t` being accessed as if it were a `uint32_t`. C 2018 6.5 7 says that is not defined. There can also be errors because the alignment requirement of a `uint32_t` may be stricter than the requirement of a `uint8_t`.

A defined way to set the bytes of `uint32_t` is:

```
uint32_t p;
memcpy(&p, arr, sizeof p); // Include <string.h> to declare memcpy.
```

Then, since this `p` is not a pointer, print it with `printf("Value of p: %08Xh\n", p);`.